# JWT improper decoding with mongoose data

Tags: node.js, json-web-token

Here is the data that i am encoding

```
{ _id: 5880c2562f109c2e17489155,
  password: '$2a$10$1TGM/Nnoii/ERt5YZFqaROJA0176bXw5wn7fF9B7.DrikVcW/Va4e',
  verified: false,
  __v: 0 }
```

and the data that i get from decoding using [jsonwebtoken](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken).

```
{ '$__': 
   { strictMode: true,
     getters: {},
     wasPopulated: false,
     activePaths: { paths: [Object], states: [Object], stateNames: [Object] },
     emitter: { domain: null, _events: {}, _eventsCount: 0, _maxListeners: 0 } },
  isNew: false,
  _doc: 
   { __v: 0,
     verified: false,
     password: '$2a$10$1TGM/Nnoii/ERt5YZFqaROJA0176bXw5wn7fF9B7.DrikVcW/Va4e',
     _id: '5880c2562f109c2e17489155' },
  _pres: 
   { '$__original_save': [ null, null ],
     '$__original_validate': [ null ],
     '$__original_remove': [ null ] },
  _posts: 
   { '$__original_save': [],
     '$__original_validate': [],
     '$__original_remove': [] },
  iat: 1484834592 }
```

If you notice the docs i should be able to access the decoded `password` field using `decoded.password` but from this case i have to use `decoded._doc.password`. Is this happening somehow because i am directly passing in the mongoose object into `jwt` or the output is fine and i should access the data by adding `_doc`. The relevant code is

```
module.exports['generateToken'] = (data)=>{
  return new Promise((fullfill,reject)=>{
    console.log(data.user);
    var token = jwt.sign(data.user,'shhhhhh');
    fullfill(token);
  });
}

module.exports['decodeToken'] = (token)=>{
 return new Promise((fullfill,reject)=>{
   jwt.verify(token,'shhhhhh',(err,decoded)=>{
     if(err)
       reject(err);
     console.log(decoded);
     fullfill(token);
   });
 });
}
```

`data.user` is the document that i got from mongoose query `findOne`.

Comment: jwt.decode instead of jwt.verify have you checked that

Comment: @AsifSaeed let me try that

Comment: @AsifSaeed that is `sync` also it is written in docs to use `verify` and not `decode` in warning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this happening somehow because i am directly passing in the mongoose object into `jwt`

Yes, instances of mongoose models have quite complicated structure inside. And `_doc` is a reference to an internal document.

To avoid accessing by `._doc`, you should encode document converted to a plain object:

```
module.exports['generateToken'] = (data)=>{
  return new Promise((fullfill,reject)=>{
    console.log(data.user);
    var token = jwt.sign(data.user.toObject(),'shhhhhh');
    fullfill(token);
  });
}
```